# Using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in moderncv.cls

Tags: moderncv, input-encodings

I am trying to compile a CV using `moderncv.cls` but have problems with the special danish characters æ,ø,å. Normally I add either `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` packages to my template but this is not really working.

The `moderncv.cls` file has the following part:

```
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \IfFileExists{lmodern.sty}%
    {\RequirePackage{lmodern}}%
    {}
```

Normally I would have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` before `fontenc`, but the `\RequirePackage` seem to mess this up. I use Texmaker and MacOS.

Does anyone know how I can add the package?

MWE:

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Lonnie} % Your first name
\familyname{Andersen} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Gladsaxevej 78, st tv, 2860 Søborg}
\mobile{+45 31444177}
\email{lonnieandersen82@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/Lonnie} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2009--2013}{Ph.D student}{DTU Wind Energy}{}{Currently finishing thesis}{}
\cventry{2003--2009}{Cand. Scient in Biomedical engineering}{DTU}{}{\textit{GPA -- 8.4}}{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It should make no real differerence if `fontenc` is loaded before or after `inputenc`. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Hi I have added MWE that runs as soon as I comment out the adress line. I have tried using \o and {\o} which sometmes does the trick but nothing works. The fontenc line is something I have added but it makes no difference.

Comment: The `inputenc` line should reflect the actual encoding of the file, which depends on the setting of the editor. Just ensure it's UTF-8 and add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Your question led me to a solution for a problem I had where the text inserted by a command in a class wasn't turning out correctly but the text in the document was. I solved it by adding `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputec}` to the class. Thanks!

And a comment to the moderators who thought this question was too localized. The example mentions Danish characters, but it could as well have been any non-ASCII characters! This means the question relates to almost every language that isn't English. I'm not really sure how to be *less* localized than that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the encoding of the file. (Although your example should have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in it.)

The `\address` macro in `moderncv` requires 2 arguments, and you are only providing one. It then tries to read the `\mobile` macro as the second argument and the error arises.

So you need:

```
\address{Gladsaxevej 78, st tv}{2860 Søborg}
```

(Or something similar) as your address line.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually just found this out before seeing your answer, had deleted two brackets by mistake. Thank you so much for the quick help, great great forum!!!